# Golang multiple-value function composition

Tags: go, function-composition

Short question to which I haven't found an answer on SO: how do I write composite function calls when an inner function has multiple return values?

Sub-question: can you cast just one of the returns from a multiple-value function without using a temp variable?

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/intnxkzSO1

```
package main

import "fmt"

func multiReturn() (int, int) {
    return 0, 1
}

func noOp(a int) int {
    return a
}

func main() {

    // Too many arguments
    fmt.Print(noOp(multiReturn()))

    // multiple-value in single-value context
    fmt.Print(string(multiReturn()))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have your outer function match the return values of the inner function

```
func multiReturn() (int, int) {
    return 10, 1
}

func noOp(a, _ int) int {
    return a
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", noOp(multiReturn()))             // output: 10
    fmt.Printf("%s", strconv.Itoa(noOp(multiReturn()))) // output: 10
}
```

On a side note string(int) will not work, you have to use the `strconv` package.

Go [play](http://play.golang.org/p/iA5HVCR-Xw)

Another option would to use a [variadic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters) parameter.

```
func noOp(a ...int) int {
    if len(a) > 0 {
        return a[0]
    }
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func singleReturn() int {
    s, _ := multiReturn()
    return s
}

func multiReturn() (int, int) {
    return 0, 1
}

func noOp(a int) int {
    return a
}

func main() {

    fmt.Print(noOp(singleReturn()))
    fmt.Print(string(singleReturn()))

    // Too many arguments
    //fmt.Print(noOp(multiReturn()))

    // multiple-value in single-value context
    //fmt.Print(string(multiReturn()))
}
```

Comment: This works, but it's not really the point - here we just reassign the multiple return to one variable and return that, so we're still only actually composing single-valued functions.

Comment: That's your only option.

Comment: @AndrewSannier What's the distinction being made between casting and function composition?  If you have something like: http://play.golang.org/p/VPyl2wf6pt, that demonstrates that you can "cast" multiple return values in some limited situations with function composition.  Some of the standard library works like this.  (e.g. `regexp.MustCompile`, `template.Must`)

Answer (score -3):

you can also return a function that returns multiple values.

```
func f() (int, int) {
    return 1, 2
}

func g() (int, int) {
    return f()
}
```

Comment: See "The expression list in the "return" statement may be a single call to a multi-valued function." in https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements for more.